# Handling multiple inserts to database from multiple sessions in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session, ado.net

I have an asp.net application which allows users to log in and saves appointments for different time slots. It is a multi-user application and multiple users can log in at the same time and book appointments.

I have a stored procedure which inserts the appointment slots data into the database which is called on save button click after slots are selected.

I am having a problem when 2 or more users try to save appointment on the same slot simultaneously. In this scenario, I want to allow only one insert and return an error message to all the other calls to insert stored procedure.

Steps to reproduce:

1. User 1 select 1 slot. User 2 select same slots as user 1.
2. User1 and User2 - fill data of the slot
3. User1 and 2 click Save button simultaneously.

This should save data of user 1 and show error to user 2 as appointment slot is booked.

In short I want to allow execution of stored procedure only once and return an error to all the other inserts.

Comment: What does not work? SQL Server uses optimistic concurrency by default. So You should get a Concurrency exception.

Comment: I would have the stored procedure or your code check if the timeslot is still available just before creating the record

Comment: Maybe a Unique constraint on the Slot data type, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Optimistic Way**

You can add a timestamp column to your appointment slot table, to maintain the integrity when multiple users are working on the same rows at the same time.

Once you add the timestamp, you need to get it to the UI, so that you can pass it back to the DB at the time of updates.

While updating the rows, if the time stamp is same, you continue with the transaction, if the timestamp has been changed, you need to rollback the transaction.

**Pessimistic Way**

Lock the Slot when someone want to book it, so that other will not be able to open it for booking, only problem with this is, when someone closes the application without any transaction, you need to unlock it through some background logic.

For more details on both the approaches, you can check this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt).

Comment: Thanks for the solution...went with the Pessimistic Way. That article is good read!

Answer (score 0):

If the *timeSlot* is the primary key or has a unique constraint then SQL does this for you.  You should design it this way.

If you want to return a message from the stored procedure you can just check for the primary key before trying to insert.